# I've just updated Angular-cli 1.0.0 and ui-router-ng2 doesn't work

Tags: angular

Can Someone help me? I've just updated Angular-cli from 1.0.0-beta.28 to 1.0.0 and ui-router-ng2 doesn't work, I get the following error :

```
ERROR in ./~/ui-router-ng2/lib/uiRouterNgModule.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router/src/router_config_loader' in 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\ui-router-ng2\lib'
```

Thanks a million

Comment: Angular v4 no longer supports deep imports.

Comment: @yurzui, is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: What do you import?

Comment: If you use webpack seems you can write some loader to replace import